# AWS ECS Task Definition: Unknown parameter in volumes[0]: "dockerVolumeConfiguration", must be one of: name, host

Tags: amazon-ecs

I am trying to run Wazuh/Wazuh docker container on ECS. I was able to register task definition and launch container using Terraform. However, I am facing an issue with "Volume"(Data Volume) while registering tak definition using AWS CLI command.

Command: aws ecs --region eu-west-1  register-task-definition --family hids --cli-input-json file://task-definition.json

Error:
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in volumes[0]: "dockerVolumeConfiguration", must be one of: name, host
2019-08-29 07:31:59,195 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

```
{
"containerDefinitions": [
  {
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "hostPort": 514,
        "containerPort": 514,
        "protocol": "udp"

      },
     {
        "hostPort": 1514,
        "containerPort": 1514,
        "protocol": "udp"

      },
      {
        "hostPort": 1515,
        "containerPort": 1515,
        "protocol": "tcp"

      },
      {
        "hostPort": 1516,
        "containerPort": 1516,
        "protocol": "tcp"

      },
      {
        "hostPort": 55000,
        "containerPort": 55000,
        "protocol": "tcp"

      }
    ],
    "image": "wazuh/wazuh",
    "essential": true,
    "name": "chids",
    "cpu": 1600,
    "memory": 1600,
    "mountPoints": [
        {
          "containerPath": "/var/ossec/data",
          "sourceVolume": "ossec-data"

        },
        {
          "containerPath": "/etc/filebeat",
          "sourceVolume": "filebeat_etc"

        },
        {
          "containerPath": "/var/lib/filebeat",
          "sourceVolume": "filebeat_lib"

        },
        {
          "containerPath": "/etc/postfix",
          "sourceVolume": "postfix"
        }
      ]

  }
],
"volumes": [
  {
      "name": "ossec-data",
      "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
      "scope": "shared",
      "driver": "local",
      "autoprovision": true
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "filebeat_etc",
    "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
    "scope": "shared",
    "driver": "local",
    "autoprovision": true
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "filebeat_lib",
    "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
    "scope": "shared",
    "driver": "local",
    "autoprovision": true
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "postfix",
    "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
    "scope": "shared",
    "driver": "local",
    "autoprovision": true
  }
}
]   
}
```

I tried by adding "host" parameter(however it supports Bind Mounts only). But got the same error.

```
    "volumes": [
  {
      "name": "ossec-data",
      "host": {
      "sourcePath": "/var/ossec/data"
    },
      "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
      "scope": "shared",
      "driver": "local",
      "autoprovision": true
    }
  }
]
```

ECS should register the task definition having 4 Data Volumes and associated mount points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue.
Removed "dockerVolumeConfiguration" parameter from "Volume" configuration and it worked.

```
"volumes": [
{
    "name": "ossec-data",
    "host": {
      "sourcePath": "/ecs/ossec-data"
    }

},
{
  "name": "filebeat_etc",
  "host": {
      "sourcePath": "/ecs/filebeat_etc"
    }

},
{
  "name": "filebeat_lib",
  "host": {
      "sourcePath": "/ecs/filebeat_lib"
    }

},
{
  "name": "postfix",
  "host": {
      "sourcePath": "/ecs/postfix"
    }
```

}
  ]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check on your version of awscli?

```
aws --version
```

According to all the documentation, your first task definition should work fine and I tested it locally without any issues.
It might be that you are using an older aws cli version where the syntax was different or parameters were different at the time.

Could you try updating your aws cli to the latest version and try again?

--

Some additional info I found:

Checking on the aws ecs cli command, they added docker volume configuration as part of the cli in [v1.80](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#180)

The main aws-cli releases updates periodically to update the commands but they don't provide much info on what specific versions of each command is changed:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst

If you update your aws-cli version things should work